# IOS App contains multiple storyboards with Objective C. How can i add more functionality with swift by adding new storyboard with old?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift3

I want to migrate my app from objective c to Swift but want to use old funcionality of story boards and adding new features into old storyboards

Comment: Storyboards are language agnostic and the same storyboard can be used with objective-c or swift code.

Comment: but when i reference a button to swift file in Login Screen after bridge creation, the application crashes completely

Comment: perhaps your button got disconnected from the outlet and its trying to reference something that doesn't exist? I agree with Dan above, there shouldn't be any issue using the same storyboard.

Comment: The error post in console is "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)"